# How to show feedback of retrieval data using find()?

Tags: mongodb

In Oracle when we fire select query then it will give number of rows selected
So In MongoDB how i can do  it this?

Comment: do you mean find({}).count() ?

Comment: You need to expand this question to make more sense.  As @manu says, what do mean specifically by select giving the number of rows?

Comment: For Example {_id:15,Name:"XYZ"} then it will show at the end 1 element Selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood right and what you want to do is to show the result of a query and then show the number of documents that matched the query, I would propose to store the cursor returned by the query and then call the `count` method on that cursor:

```
> var cursor = db.collection.find({"name":"XYZ"})
> cursor
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c4b07b0d8cc917ba53ffc7e"), "name" : "XYZ" }
> cursor.count()
> 1
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: That i know but i need that with the Data and after data it will print it like 15 rows selected..

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do. What do those 15 rows represent? The number of elements returned by the query?

Comment: I changed the answer to what I think should solve your problem. Take a look and see if it helps.

Comment: Hi, could you mark the answer as complete if it helped you?